# Call a function periodically in a distributed multiple containers/processes environment?

Tags: c#, kubernetes

I just took over a project and one of the functional requirements is to call a function every 10 minutes. I found the following code

```
async Task Run(CancellationToken cancel)
{
    while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await DoSomething(cancel);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), cancel);
    }
}
```

However, I found the application is deployed to Kubernetes with multiple instances (`replicaCount > 1`). The logs show the function is called twice every 10 minutes when `replicaCount == 2`.

How to make sure the function is called once by multiple containers?

Comment: You'll have to find a way to sync the invocations. You can use external services (e.g. Redis) to check if the function was already invoked.

Comment: It actually uses Redis for cache. How to use it to check it the function was already invoked using redis?

Comment: Make it kubernetes responsibility? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use external service like `Redis`.
so when doing task call Redis and set last calling time.

```
async Task Run(CancellationToken cancel)
{
    // abstraction view of redis connection
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();  

    while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await DoSomething(cancel);
        // Program.REDISDOYINGKEY specific key
        cache.StringSet(Program.REDISDOYINGKEY, DateTime.Now); 
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), cancel);
    }
}
```

you can see this post for refdis [link1](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/redis-distributed-cache-asp-net-core-csharp-redis-examples/)

Comment: It sets the Key `cache.StringSet(Program.REDISDOYINGKEY, DateTime.Now);`; but never use it in the code. Is there any code missing?

Comment: yes, but when you need to know when task DoSomething was run, you get from `var latestRun = Convert.ToDatetime(cache.StringGet(Program.REDISDOYINGKEY)) `;

Comment: Hmm, I guess a distributed lock is needed too to prevent racing problem when reading the key.

Comment: `Redis` itself manages `Race Condition`. Don't worry about it.

Comment: There will be two steps 1) read the Redis key for last run time. 2) set the key if last run time is longer than the interval, and run the function. There will be racing issue if two processes run the steps at the same time? (Process 1 read the key => Process 2 read the key => Process 1 write the key and run the function=> Process 2 write key and run the function.)

Comment: * key constant in your hard code like public const string REDISDOYINGKEY = "RunDoShom";

Comment: but your steps are ---- 1- after the task run, you set the current DateTime. your problem is what about 2 are more process SetString simultaneously?  Redis Process and manage the multi requests.

Comment: Yes, the problem is there are multiple processes `GetString` (for the completed logic) and `SetString` simultaneously.